# bash: gdb: No such file or directory

Tags: rust, gdb, stm32f4discovery

I am following the official documentation of [Discover Rust](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/discovery/05-led-roulette/flash-it.html). I am trying to flash the program into STM32F3. The [Flash chapter](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/discovery/05-led-roulette/flash-it.html) asks to execute this command

```
<gdb> -q target/thumbv7em-none-eabihf/debug/led-roulette
```

but it returns

```
bash: gdb: No such file or directory
```

As advised, my location is

```
naufil@Naufil:~/Desktop/discovery/src/05-led-roulette
```

and there is indeed `led-roulette` file inside `debug` folder. I have also made user if gdb is installed by executing

```
$ which -a gdb
/usr/bin/gdb
```

Comment: Are you actually typing the `<` and `>`? If so, don't.

Answer (score 2):

From immediately below that command in the documentation you linked:

> **NOTE:** `<gdb>` represents a GDB program capable of debugging ARM
>   binaries. This could be `arm-none-eabi-gdb`, `gdb-multiarch` or `gdb`
>   depending on your system -- you may have to try all three.

Answer (score 2):

All I had to do was remove the greater and less than characters:

```
gdb -q target/thumbv7em-none-eabihf/debug/led-roulette
```